# Converting this json data into a csv file in PHP

Tags: php, json, csv

my JSON data pattern is as follows:

```
{
    "Contestants": [
        {
            "Province": "Ontario",
            "Classification": "LSPI,,",
            "ClassificationDate": "2021",
            "RegistrationStatus": "Registered",
            "FirstName": "Kyle",
            "LastName": "Straunf",
            "Gender": "M",
            "AGE": null,
            "DOB": "02/08/2003",
            "Clubs": [
                {
                    "Clubname": "Penguins",
                    "Code": "MPNO",
                    "Clubid": "200"
                }
            ],
            "Email": null,
            "Language": "E",
            "ChallengeData": null
        },
        {
            "Province": "Alberta",
            "Classification": "LSPI,,",
            "ClassificationDate": "2021",
            "RegistrationStatus": "Registered",
            "FirstName": "Alexander",
            "LastName": "Kentwood",
            "Gender": "M",
            "AGE": null,
            "DOB": "08/16/2005",
            "Clubs": [
                {
                    "Clubname": "Elegant Dolphins",
                    "Code": "ZGIA",
                    "Clubid": "300"
                }
            ],
            "Email": null,
            "Language": "E",
            "ChallengeData": null
        }  
    ]
    
}
```

I managed to get the data like below, it prints but I'm having trouble printing each csv lines headers and data without it being overwritten. What's a good way to output it into a csv file with the keys as columns headers.

```
$all_data = json_decode($json_stream, true);

foreach ($all_data as $record) {
    foreach ($record as $rec) {
        foreach ($rec as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                foreach ($value as $value2) {
                    foreach ($value2 as $key2 => $value2) {
                        echo "<p> key: $key2 . value: $value2</p>";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p> key: $key . value: $value</p>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for the expected output, I'd like all the keys to be column headers like the picture below but continued with the other headers and so on.

[image: ex]

Classification section:

At the top is how it looks like presently however below is how it would be better

[image]

Comment: Your json is nested. How should that be dealt in the CSV? Share an expected output.

Comment: Updated, basically all the keys in one row as columns. Clubs can be like clubname, code, clubid, all columns since it's a nested array

Comment: Yes but what if there are multiple entries in clubs?

Comment: Ok, I am not talking about keys but multiple entries of such types. Can there be more than 1 club inside clubs?

Comment: What if they are in more than one club? The fact that clubs is an array of objects implies this case.

Comment: @answerSeeker Ok, you could have made that an object instead of an array as a better representation but never mind.

Comment: Actually never mind. Just looked at the json again., There are multiple clubs! One club array holds 1 or more club objects

Comment: @answerSeeker Your change of direction isn't clear now. Multiple clubs inside a single key `Clubs`?

Comment: @answerSeeker So share an expected output accordingly.

Comment: Ok so basically, you can add them as another column header so the next one is like clubs2.clubname, clubs2.code, clubs2.clubid. THen it increments for the number of clubs for one contestant

Comment: @answerSeeker This is what I have so far. https://onlinephp.io/c/7dc08 Run and test this on your machine. I will write an answer with an explanation tomorrow morning.

Comment: wow, genius! thanks very much, it works pretty well.  I just have one question though, if you can't do it don't worry about it. The  classification field eg     "Classification": "LSPI,,", which is column S can be categorized as 3 fields: S, SB, SM. It will have a maximum of 3 values so with: "Classification": "LSPI,SB6,SM6",  LSPI is column S, SB6 is  column SB, and SM6 would column SM. Is there a way to separate Classification into those 3 columns? That's the  last mod i'm wondering about

Comment: @answerSeeker Maybe mate. What would be the column headers?

Comment: Yes it would be the column headers

Comment: I am still a little lost with this. Can you share a sample example in your question?

Comment: Ok Sorry, I updated the question with visuals. "Classifications will become 3 columns which are S, SB, SM. The first value belongs to S, 2nd belongs to SB, 3rd belongs to SM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First step is to get the maximum no. of clubs. This is important to maintain the order of the column headers.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function getMaxClubs($data){
    $max_clubs = 0;
    foreach($data as $value){
        $max_clubs = max($max_clubs, count($value['Clubs']));
    }
    return $max_clubs;
}
```

- Second is to get the column headers. In here, we only proceed to the keys after the `Clubs` key once we have processed all the club keys which has maximum no. of clubs. We do this to maintain the order of the keys, a.k.a column headers.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

function getHeadersRow($data, $max_clubs){
    $columns = [];

    foreach($data as $value){
        foreach($value as $k => $v){
            if($k === 'Classification'){
                $columns['SM'] = $columns['SB'] = $columns['S'] =  true;
            }elseif($k === 'Clubs'){
                if(count($v) !== $max_clubs) break;
                $max_clubs = -1; // indicating club keys are processed to avoid repetition
                $cnt = 0;
                foreach($v as $club_data){
                    $cnt++;
                    foreach($club_data as $club_key => $club_value){
                        $columns[ $club_key. $cnt] = true;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $columns[ $k ] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return array_keys($columns);
}
```

- Now, we loop row by row. We append additional empty row entries for `Clubs` values if they are not having a count of `$max_clubs`.

**Full Code:**

```
<?php

$json = <<<EOD
{
    "Contestants": [
        {
            "Province": "Ontario",
            "Classification": "LSPI,,",
            "ClassificationDate": "2021",
            "RegistrationStatus": "Registered",
            "FirstName": "Kyle",
            "LastName": "Straunf",
            "Gender": "M",
            "AGE": null,
            "DOB": "02/08/2003",
            "Clubs": [
                {
                    "Clubname": "Penguins",
                    "Code": "MPNO",
                    "Clubid": "200"
                },
                {
                    "Clubname": "What Dolphins",
                    "Code": "AIZG",
                    "Clubid": "498"
                }
            ],
            "Email": null,
            "Language": "E",
            "ChallengeData": null
        },
        {
            "Province": "Alberta",
            "Classification": "LSPI,TEST2,TEST3",
            "ClassificationDate": "2021",
            "RegistrationStatus": "Registered",
            "FirstName": "Alexander",
            "LastName": "Kentwood",
            "Gender": "M",
            "AGE": null,
            "DOB": "08/16/2005",
            "Clubs": [
                {
                    "Clubname": "Elegant Dolphins",
                    "Code": "ZGIA",
                    "Clubid": "300"
                },
                {
                    "Clubname": "Weird Dolphins",
                    "Code": "ZGIA2",
                    "Clubid": "301"
                },
                {
                    "Clubname": "Favorite Dolphins",
                    "Code": "ZGIA3",
                    "Clubid": "302"
                }
            ],
            "Email": null,
            "Language": "E",
            "ChallengeData": null
        }  
    ]
    
}
EOD;

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$max_clubs = getMaxClubs($data['Contestants']);
$headers = getHeadersRow($data['Contestants'], $max_clubs);

$fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w+');

fputcsv($fp, $headers);
fputcsv($fp, array_fill(0, count($headers), ''));// empty next line for elegance

foreach($data['Contestants'] as $contestant_data){
    $row = [];

    foreach($contestant_data as $key => $value){
        if($key === 'Classification'){
            $row = array_merge($row, explode(",", $value));
        }elseif($key === 'Clubs'){
            foreach($value as $club){
                $row = array_merge($row, array_values($club));
            }
            $row = array_merge($row, array_fill(0, ($max_clubs - count($value)) * 3, ''));
        }else{
            $row[] = $value;
        }
    }

    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}

fclose($fp);


function getMaxClubs($data){
    $max_clubs = 0;
    foreach($data as $value){
        $max_clubs = max($max_clubs, count($value['Clubs']));
    }
    return $max_clubs;
}

function getHeadersRow($data, $max_clubs){
    $columns = [];

    foreach($data as $value){
        foreach($value as $k => $v){
            if($k === 'Classification'){
                $columns['SM'] = $columns['SB'] = $columns['S'] =  true;
            }elseif($k === 'Clubs'){
                if(count($v) !== $max_clubs) break;
                $max_clubs = -1; // indicating club keys are processed to avoid repetition
                $cnt = 0;
                foreach($v as $club_data){
                    $cnt++;
                    foreach($club_data as $club_key => $club_value){
                        $columns[ $club_key. $cnt] = true;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $columns[ $k ] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return array_keys($columns);
}
```